# How to mute a FaceTime iPhone call on OS X through a shortcut?

Tags: macos, facetime, shortcut, call, continuity

When using FaceTime on OS X 10.10 to initiate a call using the iPhone, is there a shortcut that allows me to mute the call from the keyboard?

[image: phone call in Facetime]

Is there a keyboard shortcut (or a way to setup a shortcut) to trigger the *Mute* function?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes you can! Here are the steps:

1. Open Automator and create an Automator Service, with a single Run AppleScript action, containing the following code:

   *High Sierra and later:*

   ```
   tell application "System Events" to tell process "Notification Center"
       if checkbox "Mute" of window 1 exists then
           click checkbox "Mute" of window 1
       end if
   end tell
   ```

   *Sierra and earlier*:

   ```
   tell application "System Events"
       if checkbox "Mute" of window 1 of application process "FaceTime" exists then
           click checkbox "Mute" of window 1 of application process "FaceTime"
       end if
   end tell
   ```
2. Set the service to receive "no input" and to work in "any application", save it with a name of your choosing.
3. Now, go into the Shortcuts tab in the Keyboard preferences in System Preferences, and click on Services. The newly created service should be at the bottom, under the name you chose. Click on the service, then click on "add shortcut" to its right, and specify a shortcut to your liking.
4. You may have to grant Automator and/or FaceTime access in Accessibility in the Privacy tab of the Security and Privacy preferences.

That's it! You should now have a service set up, tied to the shortcut you chose that can be accessed from anywhere.

Comment: Thanks - this is brilliant! I had to allow Automator to use the assistive services in System Preferences for this to work, but after that it's working great! I've assigned it to `Ctrl+Alt+M`

Comment: My pleasure! I think I'll add that as a fourth step for completeness.

Comment: In El Capitan (OS X 10.11) I had to make the following changes for the script to work: 1. I had to change the two instances of "checkbox" in the script to "button". 2. To use as a shortcut, I had to grant FaceTime, not Automator, access in Accessibility in the Privacy tab of the Security and Privacy preferences. (But if you want to test the script from Automator, then it too needs to be granted access.)

Comment: I'm on 10.11.6 and "button" did not work but "checkbox" still did. I did have to grant FaceTime access.

Comment: This would have been better as a comment, because it doesn't answer the question. I'll update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: The script above does not work on High Sierra as the FaceTime window is then part of the Notification Center and not of the FaceTime application any more. On High Sierra you can use: `tell application "System Events" to tell process "Notification Center" to click checkbox "Mute" of first item of windows`

Comment: @Servy Thanks for keeping the answer up-to-date, I've edited this into the answer.